# What is wrong with this ANTLR Grammar? Conditional statement nested parenthesis

Tags: antlr, grammar, interpreter, antlr4, antlrworks

I've been tasked with writing a prototype of my team's DSL in Java, so I thought I would try it out using ANTLR. However I'm having problems with the 'expression' and 'condition' rules.

The DSL is already well defined so I would like to keep as close to the current spec as possible.

```
grammar MyDSL;
// Obviously this is just a snippet of the whole language, but it should give a 
// decent view of the issue.

entry
    : condition EOF
    ;

condition
    : LPAREN condition RPAREN
    | atomic_condition
    | NOT condition
    | condition AND condition
    | condition OR condition
    ;

atomic_condition
    : expression compare_operator expression
    | expression (IS NULL | IS NOT NULL)
    | identifier
    | BOOLEAN
    ;

compare_operator
    : EQUALS
    | NEQUALS
    | GT | LT
    | GTEQUALS | LTEQUALS
    ;

expression
    : LPAREN expression RPAREN
    | atomic_expression
    | PREFIX expression
    | expression (MULTIPLY | DIVIDE) expression 
    | expression (ADD | SUBTRACT) expression
    | expression CONCATENATE expression
    ;

atomic_expression
    :  SUBSTR LPAREN expression COMMA expression (COMMA expression)? RPAREN
    | identifier
    | INTEGER
    ;

identifier
    : WORD
    ;

// Function Names
SUBSTR: 'SUBSTR';
// Control Chars
LPAREN : '(';
RPAREN : ')';
COMMA  : ',';
// Literals and Identifiers
fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;
INTEGER: DIGIT+;
fragment LETTER : [A-Za-z@$#];
fragment CHARACTER : DIGIT | LETTER | '_';
WORD: LETTER CHARACTER*;
BOOLEAN: 'TRUE' | 'FALSE';
// Arithmetic Operators
MULTIPLY : '*';
DIVIDE   : '/';
ADD      : '+';
SUBTRACT : '-';
PREFIX: ADD| SUBTRACT ;
// String Operators
CONCATENATE : '||';
// Comparison Operators
EQUALS   : '==';
NEQUALS  : '<>';
GTEQUALS : '>=';
LTEQUALS : '<=';
GT       : '>';
LT       : '<';
// Logical Operators
NOT : 'NOT';
AND : 'AND';
OR  : 'OR';
// Keywords
IS  : 'IS';
NULL: 'NULL';
// Whitespace
BLANK: [ \t\n\r]+ -> channel(HIDDEN) ;
```

The phrase I'm testing with is

```
(FOO == 115 AND (SUBSTR(BAR,2,1) == 1 OR SUBSTR(BAR,4,1) == 1))
```

However it is breaking on the nested parenthesis, matching the first ( with the first ) instead of the outermost (see below). In ANTLR3 I solved this with semantic predicates but it seems that ANTLR4 is supposed to have fixed the need for those.

[image: ANTLRWorks Parse tree]

I'd really like to keep the `condition` and the `expression` rules separate if at all possible. I have been able to get it to work when merged together in a single `expression` rule (based  on examples here and elsewhere) but the current DSL spec has them as different and I'm trying to reduce any possible differences in behaviour.
Can anyone point out how I can get this all working while maintaining a separate rule for `conditions' and`expressions`? Many thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grammar seems fine to me.

There's one thing going wrong in the lexer: the `WORD` token is defined before various keywords/operators causing it to get precedence over them. Place your `WORD` rule at the very end of your lexer rules (or at least after the last keywords which `WORD` could also match).

Comment: Aaah, so simple yet so frustating. Thankyou! Also thankyou for your blog I have been learning a lot of very helpful things there.

For this language, there are no reserved key words as such, just various words used as controls (eg, I could create an identifier NULL and 'NULL IS NULL' would be a valid condition). Should I be defining tokens for all the control words, or leave them as implicit tokens?

Comment: @Trasvi, no problem and glad you liked my blog.